# Reference to a generic `UIHostingController`

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have a Coordinator that holds a reference to three different SwiftUI `UIHostingController`s. They are sequential so there will never be two of them active at the same time. Therefore, I thought I could reduce the number of references and just keep one generic reference.

My code looks like this:

```
final class Coordinator {
    private var currentIntroViewHost: UIHostingController<AnimationIntroView>?
    private var currentNoValidTicketsViewHost: UIHostingController<NoValidTicketsView>?
    private var currentErrorViewHost: UIHostingController<ErrorViewSwiftUI>?
}
```

What I kind of want to achieve is this:

```
final class Coordinator {
    private var currentViewHost: UIHostingController<View>?
}
```

However, using a protocol that all three of these views conform to, seems not to work. I tried it like this:

```
protocol GenericView: SwiftUI.View {}

final class Coordinator {
    private var currentViewHost: UIHostingController<GenericView>?
}
```

I receive the compiler error:

> Type 'any GenericView' cannot conform to 'View'

Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: You could declare the variable as a general `UIViewController` instead, unless there's a specific reason why your UIKit code needs to know it's a hosting controller?

Comment: Ah sometimes it can be that easy. That totally works for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [@ScottM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326518/scottm) in the comments, I was able to use to my benefit that a `UIHostingController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. In my example, there is no need that the Coordinator knows that the current view is of type `UIHostingController`.

So my solution looked like this:

```
final class Coordinator {
    private var currentViewController: UIViewController?
}
```